# While loop break after n number

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create new li after every 16th anchor tags in while loop. For example if 48 anchor tags so li should divide into 3 sets of li, each with 16 anchor tags.

```
<li>
    <a href="#" data-id="1"><img src="img/temp/1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="2"><img src="img/temp/2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="3"><img src="img/temp/3.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="4"><img src="img/temp/4.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="5"><img src="img/temp/5.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="6"><img src="img/temp/6.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="7"><img src="img/temp/7.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="8"><img src="img/temp/8.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="9"><img src="img/temp/1.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="10"><img src="img/temp/2.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="11"><img src="img/temp/3.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="12"><img src="img/temp/4.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="13"><img src="img/temp/5.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="14"><img src="img/temp/6.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="15"><img src="img/temp/7.jpg" /></a>
    <a href="#" data-id="16"><img src="img/temp/8.jpg" /></a>
</li>
```

I tried with below code, but stuck where to end while and start again.

```
<<li>
<?php 
$counter = 1;
while( have_rows('our_clients') ):the_row(); 
$image = get_sub_field('image');
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="<?php echo $counter;?>"><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" /></a>
<?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
</li>>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `$counter` inside while loop with [`%` Modulus operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) for  `16`, if `$counter % 16 == 0` that means your loop is done 16 times, therefore close and open li tags, and do the same for all multiple of 16.

```
<li>
<?php 
$counter = 0;
while( have_rows('our_clients') ):the_row();
    if($counter > 0 && $counter % 16 == 0)
        echo '</li><li>';

    $image = get_sub_field('image');
?>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-id="<?php echo $counter;?>"><img src="<?php echo $image;?>" /></a>
<?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
</li>
```

Comment: Works fine, but creating extra li set with empty anchor tags. I am using bxslider so 1 li is empty.

Comment: 48 records, created 4 list of 16 anchors, but 1 is empty??

Comment: got the issue, condition should be `if($counter > 0 && $counter % 16 == 0)` .. see my updated answer